# List job runs created through Azure VM managed identity in Databricks

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-databricks, azure-managed-identity, databricks-workflows

Do we have a solution in python to list job runs that are created using Azure VM managed identity in Azure Databricks.

Appreciate the help!

I am getting http 403 error when using managed identity library in python

```py
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential  
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential() 
# Obtain an access token  
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential  
credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
access_token = credentials.get_token("management.azure.com/") 
headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' } 
# Set the URL for the Databricks REST API 
endpoint url = "databricks_url" + '/api/2.0/clusters/list' 
# Make the REST API call to the Databricks endpoint 
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)  
print(response.json())
```

Comment: please show how do you that? code/command-line, etc.

Comment: Edit your question to include this code

Comment: Is this identity added to the workspace?

Comment: Azure VM has contributor role to Databricks

Answer (score 0):

If managed identity isn't added into the Databricks workspace yet, then having only access token isn't enough - you also need to provide an additional access token for accessing Azure management API (the `https://management.core.windows.net/` resource URL), and it should be provided as the `X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token` header, together with Databricks Workspace Resource ID as the `X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id`.

And then you need to generate the access token to the for Databricks workspace resource (`2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d`) that should be sent as bearer token.

This specific scenario is [described in the details the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#--workspace-level-api-access-for-service-principals-that-are-not-azure-databricks-users).

Comment: Managed Identity is already added to the workspace.I cannot follow the documentation since I don't have service principal.

Comment: If it’s already added, then your solution is 2nd paragraph. You were generating AAD token for the wrong scope - see above in the same doc. (MI behaves like SP, you simply don’t have secret - you still generate tokens for a specific resource).

Comment: Here is an example for service principal, but you can see the correct scope: https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/blob/main/dbsql-with-aad-token/dbsql-with-aad-token.py#L17

Comment: Thanks I was able to resolve with scope.